# Why does Bundler refuse to accept a gem with no version specified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

The command:

```
bundle update
```

The error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "fog-core":
  In Gemfile:
    fog was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      fog-google (<= 0.1.0) was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
        fog-core

    fog was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      fog-internet-archive was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
        fog-core (~> 1.45)
```

Bundler keeps finding that `fog-core` with no version specified is incompatible with `fog-core (~> 1.45)`. I would think that no version in the `.gemspec` file means that any version is acceptable, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

This is happening with Bundler version 1.16.1 on a very large project, after attempting to upgrade the version of `fog-aws`.

My solution so far has been to fork every dependency, making the following change:

```
--- a/foo.gemspec
+++ b/foo.gemspec

-  spec.add_dependency "fog-core"
+  spec.add_dependency "fog-core", "~> 1.45"
```

...but that's a stupid thing to have to do. There's got to be a better way.

Comment: do you have a dependency to "fog" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day and a half of single-stepping through Bundler, I have arrived at an answer:

If both of the following things happen:

1. Bundler looks at a conflicting version of a package (such as `librato-metrics`) before finding the right version.
2. Another error of any kind happens, either before or after #1.

...Bundler will show the resolved conflict error along with all the other errors, even though the conflict was actually resolved and doesn't need to be addressed.